# OOP PHP Class Variable Scope

Tags: php, oop

I decided to begin looking into pdo last night. Right now i am converting my procedural code to oop. I have had a few issues but have been able to figure them out through tutorials etc. One that i cannot find a clear answer on is global variables.

I have various classes

User ( Allows me to gather all user data )

Login

Registration

Utilities

Database

Utilities includes things like IPsniffer, User Input Sanitation, and various other functions.

Database just allows me to condense the lines needed for a query or insert, etc.

I need utilities and Database in nearly all of the other classes. I was looking into various ways of passing the variables to the functions. But there seems to be mixed feelings against each method.

( I also have a few variables like $url, $path, etc. that need to be included in each class this is why i am trying to avoid paramaters )

So my question is this. Should i just use parameters and assign everything in a construct? Use globals? What would be a simple way to set those variables to have a global scope that is considered "Good" practice. Or should i create a new instance of the class wherever i need it ( Inside the other classes )

( Also i have an autoloader in the header of the page not sure if there is a way to utilize that within the classes, i do not want to duplicate the code over and over )

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not set up a registry? Or even a base class that has the said `objects` set inside it while the other classes extend that?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question depends highly on the design you do with your application (this "depending on design" is most likely the reason you have mixed feeling, but telling so won't change your feelings).

However, the most likely sane answer is to pass as constructor parameters (constructor injection) and also to not use `new` *inside* a constructor regardless of which design you follow.

Comment: Is there any sort of implementation i can use to make this process a bit cleaner. I do not want to use new Login($url, $path, $utilities, $db, etc. ) wherever it is needed. Assuming this is what you are talking about.

Comment: @ICJ Consider the factory or builder pattern, but be aware that too many parameters in the constructor often suggests that there is something wrong with the design of your class. In this case `new Login($url, $path, $utilities, $db)` tells me that `Login` does more than it should do.

Comment: A few of the functions within the class send information for example when a user requests a forgot password email, i have that processing within the class, i thought it would be a bit cleaner since i could have one mail function that can be used to send the emails ( for other functions as well ) is this the wrong approach?

Comment: @ICJ It's difficult to say what you should do without knowing the application design. If I took a stab in the dark, I'd probably end up designing an `EmailSender` that is passed as a dependency for anything that sends emails, so you don't need to pack it all in one class.

Comment: That is the way i have it set up, i ended up using this

    `$this->utilities = $utilities;     
                   
    foreach ($this->utilities->helpers() as $key => $value) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }`

The variables here are mainly system paths. Not sure if this is bad practice or not but i can specifically define each variable that i need and i do not have to worry about it interfering or being interfered with by any other variable with similar names since it is not being called using global and i am not using it as a parameter.

( I tried displaying it as code )

Comment: @ICJ: You normally have a main script. In that main script create the objects you expect to use with the request. You can then do either an eager or lazy-loading here, for starters, eager-loading is perhaps more straight forward and will help you to kill bugs in code quicklier. If the `Login` is used once, create it once, then pass it around. The design of your classes should defer the differences and variations. And divide your objects into two categories: Those which do something and those which create objects (the said builder or factory pattern can give some insight here).